# cannot find Jetty 6 to 7 converter

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I will need the **Jetty6to7 conversion tool** to update my Geoserver's Jetty.

I go [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Upgrade_from_Jetty_6_to_Jetty_7)

I reach **step 1**, I hit the link http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/120259186/jetty6to7-1.0.jar and I get **All Codehaus services have been terminated**`

So where I can find the Jetty6to7 conversion tool? Is there **any other official source**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That tool is no longer available.

Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) in early 2010.

[Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are officially EOL](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) as of 2014.

There's also no conversion tooling for Jetty 7 to 8 or Jetty 8 to 9.

The only thing the `Jetty6to7.jar` did was change `org.mortbay.jetty.*` to `org.eclipse.jetty.*` in your code.  There was no XML conversion, no Classname conversion, no Usage conversion, etc ...  This was possible back when that tool was written as the classes had just migrated to the Eclipse Foundation.

But the project has moved on, and is now so far away from the old Jetty 6 style and behaviors, that even the basic concepts present in Jetty 6 are no longer valid and eligible for conversion.

Examples:

- Jetty 9 has 1 connector type (no more BIO connectors, its all NIO based.  Jetty 6 had 6 connector types)
- Jetty 9 has composable connectors that address the modern concerns around protocol negotiation / TLS 1.2. (Jetty 6 had a 2 versions of each unique protocol)
- Jetty 9 configures based on a hierarchy of HttpConfiguration objects. (Jetty 6 directly configured the connectors)
- Jetty 9 de-emphasizes modifying XML in favor of a module, property, and ini based startup that utilizes a `${jetty.base}` vs `${jetty.home}` split.  (Jetty 6 has a classic unified, modify the distribution, startup and configuration. Based on a custom config language [start.config] and OPTIONS lists that required internal knowledge of Jetty to properly setup in the correct order for it to function)